# How to raise an event without the full postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two controls in an UpdatePanel; a checkbox and a timepicker.

When I click the checkbox (event CheckedChanged) it is supposed to make the timepicker editable (ReadOnly = false) and vice-versa. I want the event CheckedChanged raised without doing a full postback.

Is there a workaround without doing it in javascript? I don't know well how triggers on an UpdatePanel are managed.

Thanks!

(asp.net 4.0, C#)

Comment: So you don't want to handle the event server-side, and you also don't want to handle it with Javascript? Hm, I'm not sure there are other alternatives than that. Unless I misunderstand your question.

Comment: I want to handle the event server-side. I just don't want to do a full postback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using an UpdatePanel will cause a full postback. So if you don't want that, you'd have to use client-side JavaScript.

It's not very complex. Find someone who can write the JavaScript for you, this is not rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

You can add code to your OnInit and OnLoad to skip executing the code that they contain by checking for Request.IsPostback and if a particular control caused it (the postback); e.g:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="MyCheckbox" AutoPostBack="true" />


if(this.Request.IsPostback && this.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == this.MyCheckbox.ID)
{
    return;
}
```

Because I didn't test this, if your checkbox is nested in other controls, which would result in its ClientID and UniqueID to be prepended parent controls' ID values, then test those 2 properties above. Also, you can change that condition to mean the opposite, obviously, so that you can wrap the complete body code in that IF block (if that's what you prefer, or if you dislike multiple return statements in one method).

I hope I understood well - this would save some processing; however, it may have negative side effects (e.g. if you have code that adds controls to the control-tree dynamically, within init/load methods on the server, then you DO want those to execute always, even in this case; otherwise, the viewstate of those dyn controls will become invalid).